# cant understand how to return string from function in C

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

```
    void add()
    {    
    char name[50], surname[50], usern[50];

    int id, birth, amount;
    printf("Enter your name, surname and your year of birth:\n");
    scanf("%s %s %d", &name, &surname, &birth);
    printf("Enter your ID, username and your total amount:\n");
    scanf("%d %s %d", &id, &usern, &amount);
    const char *pass1=function(usern);  
    }

  const char *function (char usern[50])
  {
    char temp;
    int i=0;
    int j;
    j = strlen(usern) - 1;
    while (i < j) 
    {
      temp = usern[i];
      usern[i] = usern[j];
      usern[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
    return usern;   
  }
```

I call 'add' from 'main' to print those things and then I call 'function' to return me the `usern` string but something goes wrong.

I get the error when compiling:

> [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast--> const char *pass1=function(usern);
>   [Error] conflicting types for
>   'function'--> const char *function (char usern[50])

Comment: What is going wrong? What are you doing with `const char *pass1`? What is the expected output and what output are you getting? A broad statement like "something goes wrong" will likely get you no help. More details about the problem on the other hand will definitely help you nail the problem. :)

Comment: hello, the warnings are:
 [Warning] initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast-->  const char *pass1=function(usern);
and
[Error] conflicting types for 'function'--> const char *function (char usern[50])

Comment: i want to return the string "usern" in "pass1" by calling this function ('function')

Comment: The error is because you are trying to use `function()` before defining it. You can define the function before you use it, or add a function protoype before you use it: `const char* function(char usern[50]);` Also note @Bathsheba 's answer about possible undefined behaviour.

Comment: thank you @Sumit Chakraborty, I forgot the "const char *" in front of the definition. Now i use " printf ("%s", pass1); " in add and it prints what i wanted :)

Comment: @sniperalex117 I am confused, in the code you have posted the definition clearly contains `const char *`. Perhaps you meant the `declaration` and not the `definition`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error messages you see are due the result of not declaring the function `function` *before* using it. So the compiler implicitly declares a prototype with `int` as the default type for `function`. But the actual return type of `function` conflicts with the implicit `int` type. So you get those errors.

Note that this implicit int rule is no longer valid as it's been removed since C99. This used to be the case in C89/C90.

The solution is to provide a prototype for it. Add this at the top of your source file (or include it in a header file if you have one).:

```
const char *function (char *);
```

Comment: yeah, i declared the funtion as you say and it works but without * before variable
`const char* function(char usern[50]);`

Comment: @sniperalex117 `const char *function(char *);` is equivalent to `const char* function(char usern[50]);`... What you need to understand is that `usern` is not an array in the context of `function`; you **can't** pass an array to `function`. You can, however, mimic passing an array by passing a pointer.

Comment: @sniperalex117 `const char* function(char usern[50]);`, `const char* function(char *usern);` and `const char* function(char *);` are equivalent in the function prototype. The parameter name is optional in prototypes. An array decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to a function. So the fact you specify the size in the defintion as `const char* function(char usern[50]){ ..}` is irrelevant and will be ignored by the compiler. So `usern` is actually a pointer in `function`.

Comment: Also, if an answer solves your problem you should accept it.

Comment: ohh ok then, but how is `usern` a pointer? `pass1` is declared as a pointer.

Comment: @sniperalex117 that was explained in comment above: "An array decays into a pointer to its first element when passed to a function."

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime for which the return of `function` is valid is the same as the lifetime of the parameter `usern` that's passed to it.

This is because no *deep copy* of the character array is taken.

If you attempt to return `pass1` from `add` and use it, then the program behaviour would be *undefined* since `usern` would then be out of scope.

The normal thing to do here in C is to `malloc` a new string, returning a pointer to it. Don't forget to call `free` at some point.

Comment: Actually, the argument that `usern` denotes is a pointer, not an array, and that pointer points to the object that is declared in `add`. You can prove this by checking `sizeof usern`.

Comment: Also, it's not at all normal to `malloc` a new *string*. For a start, strings are not types of objects, but instead types of values, and `malloc` allocates objects, not values. More importantly, consider every standard library function in C: Does `fgets`, for example, `malloc` anything? No, yet it produces a string, doesn't it?